# Wrong Output Guess the Number

Tags: python, function

I'm making a small game that chooses a random number in the given limit and the user tries to guess the number. I tried to add chances so you could try multiple times. Why is it returning the guessed number multiplied by the chance number?

```
def guessTheNumber():
    chances = int(input('How many chances do you want: '))
    limit = int(input('Input limits: '))
    inputnum = int(input('Input number: '))
    x = 1
    while x <= chances:
        randomnum = randomNum(limit)
        if inputnum == randomnum:
            print('you won!')
            x+=1
        continue
    else:
        print('THe number was {}'.format(randomnum))
        replay()
```

When called it returns:

```
guessTheNumber():

    How many chances do you want: 3
    Input limits: 10
    Input guess: 4
    you won!
    you won!
    you won!
    The number was 4
    play again?: no
    Goodbye
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: I think you have the lines `inputnum = ...` and `randomnum = ...` backwards. Try swapping them and see if it has the output you expect.

Comment: Think carefully about your logic. Write it out longhand, in plain English, and then carefully check your code to ensure it corresponds to your intent. Especially think about when each calculation should happen, and how many times it should happen (should it be inside or outside of a given loop?).

Comment: Also, especially think about the indentation of each line of code, and whether that makes things line up to where they should be.

Comment: There's no need for `continue` at the end of the loop body. Loops automatically continue unless you break out of them.

Comment: You don't break out of the loop when the computer guesses the number correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It loops until you have won 'chances' times. Look at the indent of the various lines.

Answer (score 0):

You have the game backwards. The user is selecting a number once, and then the computer guesses every time through the loop.

You're only incrementing `x` when the computer guesses right, because `x += 1` is in the `if` block, and you don't stop the loop when the guess is correct. So you'll get `chances` `You won` messages, then the loop stops.

The correct code is:

```
def guessTheNumber():
    chances = int(input('How many chances do you want: '))
    limit = int(input('Input limits: '))
    randomnum = randomNum(limit)
    x = 1
    while x <= chances:
        inputnum = int(input('Input number: '))
        if inputnum == randomnum:
            print('you won!')
            break
        x+=1
    else:
        print('The number was {}'.format(randomnum))
        replay()
```